# IllegalArgumentException while highlighting pdf using PDFClown

Tags: pdf, pdfclown

I've been working on highlighting pdf using PDFClown and mostly its working fine however in few cases its giving the exception as provided in the below stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.sort(TextExtractor.java:633)
    at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:284)
    at org.pdfclown.samples.cli.TextHighlightSample.run(TextHighlightSample.java:60)
    at com.dhawan.poc.Highlight.main(Highlight.java:9)
```

[Link to PDF File](http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/white_paper/white_paper.pdf)

Any idea how can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of PDFClown do you use? Your stack trace does not match the current code at http://svn.code.sf.net/p/clown/code/trunk/java/pdfclown.lib but instead contains the following comparison used for sorting:

```
public int compare(
  ITextString textString1,
  ITextString textString2
  )
{
  Rectangle2D box1 = textString1.getBox();
  Rectangle2D box2 = textString2.getBox();
  if(isOnTheSameLine(box1,box2))
  {
    /*
      [FIX:55:0.1.3] In order not to violate the transitive condition, equivalence on x-axis
      MUST fall back on y-axis comparison.
    */
    int xCompare = Double.compare(box1.getX(), box2.getX());
    if(xCompare != 0)
      return xCompare;
  }
  return Double.compare(box1.getY(), box2.getY());
}
```

> *(http://svn.code.sf.net/p/clown/code/trunk/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/tools/TextExtractor.java at revision 121)*

This fix has been introduced on May 5th, 2014. If you have a PDFClown version from before 0.1.3 or a version 0.1.3 built before that date, you should update PDFClown.

Comment: I'm using PDF Clown 0.1.2 Beta downloaded from [here](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/downloads.html). I'm facing several other issues, which I've resolved on my side, few of them using the answers you've given on other posts.

Comment: Thanks anyways, I'll checkout the latest code and see if those issues are resolved :)

Comment: If you resolved some issues in your PDFClown copy based on my answers, those issues might well still be present in the current trunk. If you prefer you might want to backport that fix 55 instead. It took place only in the method mentioned.

Comment: First of all, I want to thank mkl for his competent support. Please @dShringi apply your issues/resolutions to the project's site (https://sourceforge.net/projects/clown/) so that they can be included in the fixes and benefit everybody, thanks.